# The security protocol cannot verify the incoming message

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm currently having some issues with an existing (inherited) system that was working without problems up to a few months ago (it's last use). Now we've gone to use it again, and it appears to be producing this error "The security protocol cannot verify the incoming message."

The code base creates a connection via the UserProxy service which is used for user authentication.

I've been looking around for some solutions, but have yet to come up with anything that helps in my particular situation. What's particularly puzzling is that it appears that nothing has changed with either sets of code since it was working. Anyone have any advice?

As mentioned before, this is an inherited system, and I don't normally work with WCF, so excuse my ignorance. :)

Client Configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://t5tag.circuitlink.com.au/UserService" binding="clearUsernameBinding" bindingConfiguration="myClearUsernameBinding" contract="UserProxy.IUserService" name="userService_Tcp" />
      <endpoint address="http://t5tag.circuitlink.com.au/StaffService" binding="clearUsernameBinding" bindingConfiguration="myClearUsernameBinding" contract="StaffProxy.IStaffService" name="StaffService_Tcp" />
    </client>
    <extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="clearUsernameBinding" type="CL.External.Lib.Wcf.BindingExtension.WS.ClearUsernameCollectionElement, CL.External.Lib" />
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="userService_Tcp">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="StaffService_Tcp">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <clearUsernameBinding>
        <binding name="myClearUsernameBinding" messageVersion="Soap12" />
      </clearUsernameBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!-- Added diagnostics -->
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Server Configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <clearUsernameBinding>
        <binding name="myClearUsernameBinding" messageVersion="Soap12">
        </binding>
      </clearUsernameBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="CL.Web.Service.StaffService">
        <endpoint binding="clearUsernameBinding" bindingConfiguration="myClearUsernameBinding"
          name="StaffService_Tcp" contract="CL.Web.Service.IStaffService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://t5tag.circuitlink.com.au/StaffService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="CL.Web.Service.UserService">
        <endpoint binding="clearUsernameBinding" bindingConfiguration="myClearUsernameBinding"
          name="userService_Tcp" contract="CL.Web.Service.IUserService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://t5tag.circuitlink.com.au/UserService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="clearUsernameBinding" type="CL.External.Lib.Wcf.BindingExtension.WS.ClearUsernameCollectionElement, CL.External.Lib" />
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>  
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CL.Web.Service.CustomUserNameValidator, CL.Web.Service" />            
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client Sent Message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
   <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
      <EventID>0</EventID>
      <Type>3</Type>
      <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
      <Level>8</Level>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-08-07T01:45:53.7958411Z" />
      <Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
      <Correlation ActivityID="{4cc6b3ad-4bd2-408a-b28c-ff5bba0e163e}" />
      <Execution ProcessName="TagReader" ProcessID="3656" ThreadID="1" />
      <Channel />
      <Computer>PC70-PETER</Computer>
   </System>
   <ApplicationData>
      <TraceData>
         <DataItem>
            <MessageLogTraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace" Time="2015-08-07T11:45:53.7958411+10:00" Source="TransportSend" Type="System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage">
               <Addressing>
                  <Action>http://tempuri.org/IUserService/Login</Action>
                  <To>http://t5tag.circuitlink.com.au/UserService</To>
               </Addressing>
               <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                  <s:Header>
                     <ActivityId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics" CorrelationId="a2314719-a98b-4f07-8a26-c93809fed70f">4cc6b3ad-4bd2-408a-b28c-ff5bba0e163e</ActivityId>
                     <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
                        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                           <u:Created>2015-08-07T01:45:53.599Z</u:Created>
                           <u:Expires>2015-08-07T01:50:53.599Z</u:Expires>
                        </u:Timestamp>
                        <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-11d6aeee-d0be-4888-868a-bae4c274d9f3-2">
                           <o:Username>
                              <!-- Removed-->
                           </o:Username>
                           <o:Password>
                              <!-- Removed-->
                           </o:Password>
                        </o:UsernameToken>
                     </o:Security>
                  </s:Header>
                  <s:Body>
                     <Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                        <username>XXXX@XXXX</username>
                        <password>XXXX</password>
                     </Login>
                  </s:Body>
               </s:Envelope>
            </MessageLogTraceRecord>
         </DataItem>
      </TraceData>
   </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Server Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
   <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
      <EventID>458802</EventID>
      <Type>3</Type>
      <SubType Name="Warning">0</SubType>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-08-07T01:46:00.1099767Z" />
      <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
      <Correlation ActivityID="{4cc6b3ad-4bd2-408a-b28c-ff5bba0e163e}" />
      <Execution ProcessName="CL.Web.Service" ProcessID="14168" ThreadID="9" />
      <Channel />
      <Computer>CLAPPSERVER</Computer>
   </System>
   <ApplicationData>
      <TraceData>
         <DataItem>
            <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
               <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityBindingVerifyIncomingMessageFailure.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
               <Description>The security protocol cannot verify the incoming message.</Description>
               <AppDomain>CL.Web.Service.exe</AppDomain>
               <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/SecurityProtocolTraceRecord">
                  <SecurityProtocol>System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol</SecurityProtocol>
                  <Action>http://tempuri.org/IUserService/Login</Action>
                  <To>http://t5tag.circuitlink.com.au/UserService</To>
               </ExtendedData>
            </TraceRecord>
         </DataItem>
      </TraceData>
   </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

EDIT: Here are the details on the custom binding 'clearUsernameBinding'...

```
namespace CL.External.Lib.Wcf.BindingExtension.WS
{
    public class ClearUsernameBinding : CustomBinding
    {
        private MessageVersion messageVersion = MessageVersion.None;

        public void SetMessageVersion(MessageVersion value)
        {
            this.messageVersion = value;
        }

        public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
        {
            var res = new BindingElementCollection();
            res.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement() { MessageVersion = this.messageVersion });
            res.Add(SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement());
            res.Add(new AutoSecuredHttpTransportElement());
            return res;
        }

        public override string Scheme
        {
            get
            {
                return "http";
            }
        }
    }
}
```